# How to change the qmail hostname?

Tags: email, debian, qmail

Is there a way to modify the hostname or, more precisely, remove the defaulthost from the address? When I'm sending mails issuing `qmail-inject` the recipient gets mails from an address like this: USER@stk.HOST. I want to remove stk.

Answer (score 0):

You can override this by setting the QMAILDEFAULTHOST environment variable when you run qmail-inject.  For example, if my hostname is set to a.example.com, this will inject the mail as $USER@example.com:

```
echo -e 'Subject: Test inject\n\nHello' | \
    env QMAILDEFAULTHOST=$(hostname -d) /var/qmail/bin/qmail-inject $RECIPIENT
```

See also the qmail-inject manual: http://qmail.org/man/man8/qmail-inject.html.